# How to list a possible gap

Tags: resume, work-environment, human-resources, work-experience, probation

I hope you can give me some inputs, I need some external view on my situation.

I worked for company A (very good and large company) on a project for 2 years (with a 2-year contract, until Dec 2016). 
Terminated the contract(and the project) I found, on time, another company (start-up) that I joined on January 17. The experience was terrible, very unorganized, people were getting fired every-day.
The last week of my probation period (5 months) the internal HR offered me to extend my probation signing a "mutual termination" for the next 4 months (I was basically signing to resign). I declined, saying "no" and then she told me "ok, then we fire you" I said: "ok, I do not want to stay here one more minute". I then got fired. (June 17).

In September company A, knowing I lost my job, called me again for another 2-year project were I am working at the moment.

I do not know how to list the experience with company B in my resume. I would like to avoid it. Basically, in the 3 months of unemployment I starting learning a new language, so I could extend the 3 months to 9 months.

So this is how it looks now:

- September 2017 - now: Company A
- January 2017 - June 2017: Company B
- Dec 2014 - Dec 2016: Company A

What I want to do:

- September 2017 - now: Company A
- Dec 2014 - Dec 2016: Company A

I have a gap of 9 months to fill. Options are: Learning a new language or I took a break before starting a new project (since it is the same company).

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I am also concern about a job hopping. Going from A to B then again to A.

Comment: Could someone passing here give me another opinion? Just to have more points of view. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really that bad to have Company B in your resume? Since you are already stating that your first & current period with Company A are contracts, everyone is going to understand that you have a 9-month gap in the middle anyway - and it is going to look better if you show that you were working over that period. At least it is better than "I took a break" or "I spent 9 months learning a single language"

I would not worry too much about disclosing your time working with Company B. Probation periods are just that, periods were **both you and your employer** can test the waters to see if you are happy, and both sides have the right of exiting the contract if it does not work satisfactorily.

In summary, If I were you I would just explain things as they happened: Your 2-year project finished, you tried in a different place, things didn't work out, Company A - who was very happy with your previous performance - brought you back.

Comment: Thanks. So if they ask in a next interview "what happened in company b?" would you say "I did not survive the probation period"? Or "I did not take the "offer" and as a consequence, I was fired" ?

I am afraid that if the next employer will call company B, they will never mention that details... they will simply state "we fired him".

Also saying "I did not like B and I went back to A" make me think that the next company will ask me "Who tells me that in some months you do not quit and you go back to company A again?"

Comment: You can think of it as "the company did not survive your probation period": You were not happy with the situation, and Company B, instead of making you a fully-fledged employee, was only interested on keeping you in probation. And furthermore, to me they key point here is not that you only stayed in Company B for 6 months, but that Company A brought you back as soon as they could. Company A is going to be your last employer, so their reference is going to have much more weight for future employers anyway.

Comment: And in the cv/resume would you list this just as a normal experience?

Comment: Indeed - you worked there, so you probably had time to complete a few projects/learn new technologies/skills; this is just another stage in your career. Definitely better than just learning a new language during those 6 months ;)